# How to represent binary and n-ary full tree using arrays?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I would like to represent a tree like this:

[image: Tree1]

As you can see internal nodes are empty and leaves contain strings.

What is the best way to do that using only arrays?

and if tree is n-ary like this?

[image: Tree2]

Comment: Why do you want to use "only arrays"?  This sort of thing is much easier if you implement `TreeNode` or something similar.

Comment: @azurefrog I wanna make it easy to find distance between two leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some dummy names to the nodes which doesn't have any values. Then traverse the tree either using pre/post order techniques and store the values in array.

For the first example: Using preorder

Using A as root

A, A, V10, V9, A, V8, A, A, V7, V6, A, V5, A, A, V4, V3, A, V2, V1